# How do i initialize database in SQLite3 script?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I am doing an assignment in which there is a requirement that i have to write a sqlite3 script to initialize database and create tables ...

Now i know how to do all this in SQL but not in lite. 
Actual statement is as follows

> 2.1. Create an SQL (text) document mandm_setup.sql!that can be executed from the
>   SQLite command prompt. This script should include SQL statements that do the
>   following:
>
> • Appropriately initialise your database
>
> • Create all of the tables in your database design using appropriate data types and
>   constraints, based on your design

Please Help me out here.
I am stuck

Thanks In advance.

Comment: It shouldn't be (much) different than standard SQL. Where are you going wrong, and are you getting an error message? (And why have you tagged this question MySQL?)

Comment: it says syntax error. Looks like the syntax in sqlite and Mysql is not same for creating database: create database mydb;
and the reason why i tagged mysql is that i am new to databases, and i believe experts in mysql might also know about sqlite

Comment: Please note that the instructions do not say that the script should *create* the database.

Comment: Just create the DB in some GUI tool, and then [take a dump](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#converting_an_entire_database_to_an_ascii_text_file).